# Divide two TimeSpans to get a coefficient

Tags: c#, .net, timespan, division

Given an example:

We need to calculate a size of a subsections for an audio album playback progress bar. Each track in the album has the length represented as a TimeSpan value. The total length of an album is also a TimeSpan.

I need to calculate how much weight length-wise each track has in comparison to an entire album, so I can draw it respectively on a progress bar.

I know that it is not possible to devide two TimeSpan variables as is, so I am attempting to divide .Ticks.

```
long coeff = curTrackLength.Ticks / _totalLength.Ticks;
```

Such division always results in 0. I need a more precise value. How can I achieve a more precise calculation?

An environment is a Silverlight for Windows Phone Mango.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast at least one side to `double` or `decimal` to avoid integer division.

Comment: Depending on what level of precision is required you could also divide by the TotalMilliseconds/TotalSecconds properties which are a double already.

Answer (score 0):

```
long coeff = (long) ((double) curTrackLength.Ticks / (double) _totalLength.Ticks);
```